# Omit additional matches in dataframe with string search pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to iterate through a list of stock names and prices. 'AAPL_high' works, as there is no other stock that shares a common name.

However, on 'F_high', the code below finds 'F_high', and lists additional stocks containing the string, ex. 'CF_high' and 'COF_high'. I only desire 'F_high', and no other string that contains additional characters.

```
stocks_of_interest = ['AAPL_high', 'F_high']
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    for i in stocks_of_interest:
            print(i)
            indiv = df[df['level_0'].str.contains(i)]
            print(indiv)
```

Should I pass another argument to str.contains() to refine it further, or use a different filtering methodology? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the string in dataframe. You can do.

```
stocks_of_interest = ['AAPL_high', 'F_high']
    # from listed stocks print out just their correlations
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    for i in stocks_of_interest:
            print(i)
            indiv = df.iloc[np.where(df['level_0'].values==i)]
            print(indiv)
```